# gnome 3.34 on Ubuntu18.04 via snap

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

Many sites say to install gnome 3.34 on Ubuntu 18.04 you have to just install snap (if you not have it yet) and then type

```
$ sudo snap install gnome-3-34-1804
```

I installed it with the command above and then reboot my pc, but once i logged in on Ubuntu nothing has changed and the gnome-shell versione is the same as before:

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.4
```

How can I enable or install it in the correct manner ?